# Date column error when insert into SQL Server using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pyodbc

I have a table **Billing** where it have columns

```
BILL_NO,CUSTOMER_NAME,PHONE_NO,BILLING_DATE,DELIVERY_DATE,TOTAL_AMOUNT
```

Below is the logic for deriving dates for `billing_date` and `Delivery_date`.

```
orderdate = datetime.datetime.now().date()

if deliverydate != '':

     deliverydate = datetime.datetime.strptime(deliverydate,'%d/%m/%Y').date()
else:
     deliverydate = datetime.date(9999,12,31)
```

Lets assume delivery_date value is 9999-12-31

I try to load these values into SQL Server

```
ins_query = 'INSERT INTO dbo.BILLING VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)'

data = (billno,customername,phoneno,orderdate.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'),deliverydate.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'),totalamount)

cur.execute(ins_query,data)
```

But I received the below error regarding date column

> pyodbc.DataError: ('22007', '[22007]
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when
>
> converting date and/or time from character string. (241)
>
> (SQLExecDirectW)')

How to format the date column to load in to SQL Server. I want the date format loaded in to database as in `DD/MM/YYYY` or `YYYY/MM/DD` format

Comment: What data types are BILLING_DATE and DELIVERY_DATE? It seems that you should be inserting the values as dates, and not as strings...

Comment: SQL Server stores dates in the format 2019-12-10 20:31:35.120. If you want a different format, you could create a view  based upon the BILLING table and format the date using FORMAT( BILLING_DATE, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US' ) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @bernie , The BILLING_DATE and DELIVERY_DATE columns are DATE datatype.  In that case, how should i insert the value?

Comment: @RSax , It means in the data for date arguments instead of giving ",orderdate.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')"  i have to give FORMAT(ORDER_DATE,'dd/MM/yyyy,'en-US')

Comment: @rvssankar: insert the dates as dates, and not as strings. That is to say: do NOT execute `.strftime()` on the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys for the suggestion. The problem is i have used the old OBDC sql server connection. As @bernie said, We need to pass the dates as date  by removing the .strptime().  Even though if we used that we need to have latest odbc drivers to use in the pyodbc connection. Below is the odbc driver resolve the issue.

**Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server**

```
ins_query = 'INSERT INTO dbo.BILLING VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)'

data = (billno,customername,phoneno,orderdate,deliverydate,totalamount)

cur.execute(ins_query,data)
```